# Meaning of "presently" (US vs. UK)

Tags: meaning, differences, transatlantic-differences

Citation:

> ‘Presently’ should be used with care until the Anglo-American difference of meaning has been resolved.

What difference?

Comment: Compare: Momentarily; Instantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Usage note: **presently**. In both British English and North American English, **presently** can mean ‘soon’ or ‘after a short time’: *I’ll be with you presently.* In North American English the usual meaning of **presently** is ‘at the present time’ or ‘now’: *She is presently living in Milan.* ◇ *There is presently no cure for the disease.* This use is becoming more accepted in British English, but **at present** or **currently** are usually used.”[¹](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/presently)

Comment: I think that reference is misleading in the extreme. Obviously the one and only *original* meaning of the word was "at this present moment", for both British and American speakers. Brits have simply adopted the second meaning as a common *alternative* (not a replacement) more enthusiastically than Americans. We're not "becoming more accepting" of the older usage just because Americans still tend to *only* use that. Also note there's no possibility of confusion with *is presently* - so of course we use that freely, just as we always have.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting. [OEtD claims](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=presently) the meaning relaxed in Britain to "sooner or later" by the 1560s. I take it this contradicts the claim that the British meaning developed as an alternative, not a replacement. I understand the situation to be that Brits have long used *presently* to mean "soon", but that "now" (which happens to be the original) is regaining currency. (Possibly this is a borrowing from AmEng.) OEtD and Oxford are generally very reliable sources. Of course they can still both be wrong.

Comment: OED says the "currently" sense was *Obs. (since 17th c.) in lit. Eng. (No certain instance in Shakes.) But in regular use in most Eng. dialects, and common in Sc. writers; revived in U.S. and to some extent in Great Britain in 20th c.* I must admit I didn't know until now that it this sense had become obsolete everywhere except dialects, and had actually been "revived" (esp. in AmEng). I thought it was just a long-standing archaic usage that never really went away. But both usages co-exist for most of us, and context invariably makes it clear which is intended.

Answer (score 3):

[Presently](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/presently) has two meanings:

> - In a little while (the usual meaning - both UK and US)
> - Currently (less usual - mostly US)

However, there's rarely ambiguity, since the time contexts will differ between the two meanings.  Together with a future sense, *presently* always has the meaning of *in a little while* (and both the UK and the US use it this way):

> He **will** follow presently.

And when used with the present tense, *presently* always means *currently* (unusual in the UK):

> He **is** presently in the dining room.

The moral: prefer *at present* or similar word/phrase to *presently* when you mean *now*.  As the context of your quote says:

> Clichés and jargon phrases tend to be wordy. ‘At this present moment in time’ is longer and less pleasant than either ‘now’ or **‘at present’**. ‘Presently’ should be used with care until the Anglo-American difference of meaning has been resolved.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

The standard usage of presently, means: very soon, after short period of time which most expert and professionals uses. However, others contend that it's right if you mean: at the moment, now etcetra